# TIFF16 image looks different in windows file viewer and MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tiff

**General problem description**

I have 33 TIFF16 images and I want to do some processing on them using MATLAB. So reading them is the first step. After I download an image from the web and then try to read it using MATLAB's `imread` (as well as `Tiff` and `read`). I display the image using `imshow`. The image displayed by the Windows File Viewer and MATLAB is totally different. I cannot process them since I don't trust MATLAB has read them correctly. I give more specifics of the problem now.

EDIT: If it helps, the details of the TIFF16 images are: *TIFF (16 bits per channel, ProPhoto RGB color space, lossless compression)*

**More details:**

I download an image `a0008-WP_CRW_3959.tif`. Destination: Go to [this](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/fivek_dataset/) link -> `img0008` -> Expert B (In case somebody wants to try, otherwise I have screenshots below).

I read that image in MATLAB using: `img=imread('imgFilename.tif','tiff'); imshow(img,[]);` or

```
t = Tiff('imgFilename.tif','r');
imageData = read(t);
imshow(imageData);
```

Now, I display the snapshots of **Windows file viewer**:

[image]

Next, snapshot of what **MATLAB** shows me:

[image]

Now, I have a good reason to believe that **Windows file viewer is correct**. Go the [same link as previous](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/fivek_dataset/). Scroll down to `img0008`. Hover your mouse onto the leftmost `img0008`. A thumbnail view of `Expert B` will come which looks same as what Windows shows me.

Does anybody know how to make MATLAB read and show the `tiff16` image correctly?

Comment: The file probably contains an embedded color profile.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, even I think so, since all 5 versions of the same image look the same (in MATLAB only) and they are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @MarkRansom for pointing me to the embedded color profile possibility. I believe the following solution is correct and produces the same output as Windows File Viewer.

First read the *icc-color-profile* using `iccread` command.

```
I_rgb = imread('a0008-WP_CRW_3959.tif');
outprof = iccread('sRGB.icm');
P = iccread('a0008-WP_CRW_3959.tif');
```

Then convert the image into `sRGB` profile using `makecform` and `applycform`:

```
C = makecform('icc',P,outprof);
I_cmyk = applycform(I_rgb,C);
imwrite(I_cmyk,'pep_cmyk.tif','tif')
info = imfinfo('pep_cmyk.tif');
imshow('pep_cmyk.tif');
```

The original image saved on disk and the new - `pep_cmyk.tif` - look exactly the same with Windows file viewer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you had the initiative to figure it out once you had the hint.

Comment: If it helps, here is an example of working with embedded ICC profiles in tif files, https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/10/20/embedding-an-icc-profile-into-a-tiff-file/